# Dynamic Relational Query in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a search form which has dynamic filters and I want to generate relational queries dynamically based on the presence of the different filter.

using whereHas like

```
$properties = PropertyList::where('varification_status', '1')
    ->whereHas('common_property_details', function ($query) {
        $query->where('no_bathroom', '=', '1');
    })->get();
```

How do I populate dynamic queries without using a bunch of if else statements

**Alexey Mezenin's answer is correct** and have one more doubt.
Now I can use

```
$properties = PropertyList::where('varification_status', '1')
                ->when($request['bathRooms'] > 0, function ($q) {
                    $q->whereHas('common_property_details', function ($query) {
                    $query->where('no_bathroom', '1');
                    });
                })->get();
```

but I can't use any varible inside query inside whereHas

I tried this

```
$properties = PropertyList::where('varification_status', '1')
            ->when($request['bathRooms'] > 0, function ($q) {
                $q->whereHas('common_property_details', function ($query,$bathRoom) {
                    $query->where('no_bathroom', $bathRoom);
                });
            })->get();
```

but showing the blow error

> Missing argument 2 for
>   App\Http\Controllers\PropertySearchController::App\Http\Controllers{closure}()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use a lot of `if` statements, you can use the [`when()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#conditional-clauses) method:

```
$properties = PropertyList::where('varification_status', '1')
    ->when($something === $somethingElse, function($q) {
        $q->whereHas(....);
    })
    ->when($something > $someMaximum, function($q) {
        $q->whereHas(....);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: @RahulReghunath you need to use `use()` to pass a variable into a closure scope. For example `whereHas(function($q) use($bathRoom) { .... })`